# Golang handle static folder

Tags: go, static-files

I'm not able to get files placed in static folder. I'm using gorilla mux package.

**main.go** code:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
mainRouter.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
http.Handle("/", &mainRouter)
```

Project structure:

```
static
templates
--style
--javascript
--...
main.go
```

When I hit index page:

> loclalhost:8080/cruise_schedule

I get all stylesheets and js files, but when I jump to another page:

> localhost:8080/cruise_schedule/selected_cruise/e58ed042aad24b9b87fba8917c085534

I get following errors:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/cruise_schedule/static/style/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

and:

```
http://localhost:8080/cruise_schedule/static/javascript/resources.js
```

What should I do in order to properly serve static files?

Comment: The serving is fine (clearly, since it works). The problem is you're using relative paths in your HTML where you should be using absolute paths (absolute paths begin with a `/`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Go application is not at fault here, your generated HTML output is.

Your error message says that your sub-page tries to load its CSS from `http://localhost:8080/cruise_schedule/static/...`, when it actually *should* load from `http://localhost:8080/static/...`. The first URL will not serve the static file since it's not below the `/static` prefix, and your application will probably serve its default 404 page (presumably a `text/plain` page).

To solve this, I'd suggest either using absolute paths for your CSS (`<link href="/static/...`) or using an appropriate [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag.